# In Oracle Schedule job, the "Enabled" check-box is auto-unchecked from time to time

Tags: oracle, scheduler

I have a SQL script, that will send out some email to the group.  and it needs to be running everyday at 12:00 AM.

I have just learnt to have it setup as an ORACLE Scheduler job by this "SQL DEVELOPER" tool.

After setup, everything works fine for the day-1 job, but I didn't get the same type of email for the next session ???

What I have realized is there is an "Enabled" check-box with this Scheduled Job. After the first day success running, this box has been automatically unchecked. So the same job was not executed for the next one.

I have manually tried several time, to have the box checked and applied the change. But after getting the email for the next round, this check-box becomes unchecked again.

Is there something I am missing here ? I don't think this is "SQL developer" related, as the change is made on the server side already.  But jut in case, my "SQL DEVELOPER" is of version "4.0.3.16".

Thanks,

Chun

(10/26/2016). So far it is still an open issue to me.

And here are more information I have noticed, by looking at this "ALL_SCHEDULER_JOBS" table, where you can see the scheduled job settings from table point of view.

These are 2 column value I have compared before and after a success run.

1) "ALL_SCHEDULER_JOBS.STATUS": initially it was "SCHEDULED", and after a success run, it becomes "COMPLETED".

2) "ALL_SCHEDULER_JOBS.REPEAD_INTERVAL": It is of this value all the time. "FREQ=DAILY;BYDAY=MON,TUE,WED,THU,FRI,SAT,SUN;BYHOUR=24;BYMINUTE=0;BYSECOND=0".

What could be wrong ?

Comment: Did you specify a repeat interval? If you don't it will only run once.

Comment: Yes, I did. in the "When to Execute job" drop-down section, I have selected "Repeating" option.

Comment: And you gave it a frequency, too I suppose.

Comment: Yes, Please see my updated message.